# Typing block matrices with zero blocks and separators

Tags: matrices, block

Is there a way to type something like (sorry for the strange picture)

[image]

using pmatrix or another method as simple as that? Thanks in advance.

p.s.

I'm able to create

[image]

using

```
\newcommand\bigzero{\makebox(0,0){\text{\huge0}}}
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix} & \bigzero \\ \bigzero & \begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

but I can't type the separators. I know it (and much more complex forms) can be typed using array command, but I want to use the simple matrix commands if possible.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Here, on TeX.Se I saw many similar question. Try to search site in find their solutions. Otherwise, please show, what you try so far and where you stuck. Help us to help you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Update (2023)

With `nicematrix` it's really easy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|cc}
  a & b & \Block{2-2}<\Large>{\mathbf{0}} \\
  c & d \\
  \hline
  \Block{2-2}<\Large>{\mathbf{0}} && a & b \\
  && c & d
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Original answer (2016)

Not many possibilities without explicitly using `array`, I'm afraid:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}
\newcommand{\rvline}{\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}\vline\hspace*{-\arraycolsep}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  \begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{matrix}
  & \rvline & \bigzero \\
\hline
  \bigzero & \rvline &
  \begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bigzero}{\mbox{\normalfont\Large\bfseries 0}}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{matrix}
  & \bigzero \\
\hline
  \bigzero &
  \begin{matrix}
  a & b \\
  c & d
  \end{matrix}
\end{array}\right)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive solution. The first expression is good enough for me as I can use the new command rvline in all my documents just as easy.

Comment: Nowadays `nicematrix` would be the choice